# JavaScript - Iterate over form inputs and collect values as key value pairs in object

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object-literal

I am trying to collect values from a number of input fields in a form by iterating of the inputs and then storing them as key/value pairs in a array of objects. However i am struggling to find an efficient way of doing this that does not involve a long set if if else or switch statement.

**Concept:**

```
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

**What i would like to avoid:**

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');    

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var myObject = {};

  if (i = 0) {
    myObject.val0 = inputs[i];
  } else if (i = 1) {
    myObject.val1 = inputs[i];
  } else if (i = 2) {
    myObject.val2 = inputs[i];
  } else if (i = 3) {
    myObject.val3 = inputs[i];
  } 

}
```

Any suggestions on how this may be done more efficiently? One idea i have is using bracket notation to dynamically set the key values based on a existing html element attribute maybe id, name or a custom data attribute.

Comment: I think, if I am understanding your question correctly, that an object is maybe not a great data structure for your needs.  Consider using an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead?  What you're doing can be done in an array using square bracket (`[]`) for building your object, but I'm not sure there is a compelling reason to use an object instead of an array.

Comment: readability is the only reason i have for preferring objects in this case. For instance if want to use the values to print some html `<div>myObject.val1</div>` reads better then `<div>myArray[o]</div>`. Other then that i have no objection to arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a unique `id` to each input field (to give it a key for your object).

```
<form>
  <input id="firstName" type="text">
  <input id="lastName" type="text">
  <input id="email" type="email">
  <input id="number" type="text">
</form>
```

Now save the id as the key, and the value as the value:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');    
var myObject = {};

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  myObject[inputs[i].id] = inputs[i].value;
}

console.log(myObject) // {firstName: "", lastName: "", email: "", number: ""}
```

Turn it all into a function that does it by the form:

```
function getFormValues(formId) {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#' + formId + ' input');    
    var formValues = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      formValues[inputs[i].id] = inputs[i].value;
    }

    return formValues;
}
```

All together:

```
<form id="registerForm">
  <input id="firstName" type="text">
  <input id="lastName" type="text">
  <input id="email" type="email">
  <input id="number" type="text">
</form>

getFormValues('registerForm'); // {firstName: "", lastName: "", email: "", number: ""}
```

Now you can expand on the function further so it handles array values, etc.

Comment: There where several good answers but your won out on the detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would write like so using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
const myObject = {}

inputs.forEach((element, index) => myObject[`val${index}`] = element)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should declare the variable outside the for loop or else you will end up declaring each time the for loop runs.

Also, you can use bracket notation instead of dot notation to achieve this as you have said.

```
var myObject = {};
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  myObject["val"+i] = inputs[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use bracket notation as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for the object and `getElementsByTagName` for getting the input elements.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    object = {};

function setValues() {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        object['val' + i] = inputs[i].value;
    }
    console.log(object);
}
```

```html
<form onchange="setValues()">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one expression:

```
var myObject = Object.assign(...
    Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), (inp, i) => ({ ['val'+i]: inp }))
);
```

If you want the *values* from the inputs (as you say in the text), then you need `inp.value` instead of `inp` at the right side of the expression, or with destructuring assingment:

```js
var myObject = Object.assign(...Array.from(
    document.getElementsByTagName('input'), ({value}, i) => ({ ['val'+i]: value })
));

console.log(myObject);
```

```html
<input value="hello">
<input value="world">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Loop over your elements and dynamically use the index:**

```
a[`val${i}`] = e.value;
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var inputs   = document.querySelectorAll('input'),
      myObject = Array.from(inputs).reduce(function(a, e, i) {
                    a[`val${i}`] = e.value;
                    return a;
                 }, {});
                 
  console.log(myObject)
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <button>Click me!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop throught the input fields. Something like this maybe:

```
    let inputList = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    let val = 'val';

    for (let x in inputList){
       let name = val + x;
       myObj.`${name}`= inputList[x].value;
       number++;
    }
```

Just one of many options.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**
It appears you want to populate an array of values
This should answer your question if I understood it right

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    object = [];

function setValues() {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        object.push("val" + i + ": " + inputs[i].value );
    }
    console.log(object);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValues(), false);
```

```html
<form onchange="setValues()">
  <input type="text" value="test">
  <input type="text"  value="test22">
  <input type="text"  value="test333">
  <input type="text" value="test444">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically what the [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function was made for:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');    

  var obj = [].reduce.call(inputs, (accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
    accumulator[`val${currentIndex}`] = currentValue.value
    return accumulator
  }, {})
  
  console.log(obj)
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Won't work since `inputs` is not technically an `Array`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList